# Edit a text file to change the contents at a specific line number

Tags: perl, sed, awk, gawk

I would like to change a specific line in a text file.

I have tried with this

```
perl -p -i  -e "s/JAI/ramkrishna/ if $. == 37" test.tex
```

But it is just deleting `JAI` but not writing `ramkrishna`.

Comment: consider adding an input to your question, so it is easier for us to help you, i.e. `echo "abcJAIxyx" | perl -i ...` what happens with that? Good luck.

Comment: works for me: `{ seq 36; echo hello JAI world; } | perl -p -e  "s/JAI/ramkrishna/ if $. == 37"` -- are you **sure** that JAI appears on line 37? Try: `perl -ne ' print "$. $_"' test.tex`

Comment: if its' still not working, and you've created your file on Windows and moved it to Unix/Linix, there are likely `\r\n` line endings from Windows, and they need to be coverted to `\n` line endings that Linux uses. `dos2unix test.tex` will fix that. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command works just fine. I guess you have the line number wrong?

With a `test.tex` file like this

```
aa
bb
cc
aa bb cc JAI dd ee ff
bb
cc
aa bb cc JAI dd ee ff
xx
yy
zz
```

the command

```
perl -p -i  -e 's/JAI/ramkrishna/ if $. == 7' test.tex
```

changes the file to

```
aa
bb
cc
aa bb cc JAI dd ee ff
bb
cc
aa bb cc ramkrishna dd ee ff
xx
yy
zz
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working. May be that time I was doing something nasty.

Comment: Now I would like to change the line number with an user input, like
count=7
perl -p -i  -e 's/JAI/ramkrishna/ if $. == $count' test.tex

but it is not working.

Comment: @ramkrishna: How are you setting `count`? Is it an environment variable? You can access those through `%ENV`. Try `count = 7 perl -e'print $ENV{COUNT}'`.

Comment: Let me tell you finally what I want. In a folder I have several .png files and I have to put those .png files in a test.tex file after the specific line say 37. For that I wrote a script file as follows:
count=37
for f in *.png
do
perl -p -e "s/JAI/\n\\\begin{frame}\\\frametitle{'$f'} \n\\\includegraphics[width=13cm,height=8cm]{'$f'}\n\\\end{frame}/ if $. == '$count'" test.tex
 count=$((count+5))
done

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '37s/JAI/ramkrishna/' filename
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working.

Now I would like to change the line number with an user input, like count=7
sed '('$count')s/JAI/ramkrishna/' filename

but its not working.